# Using JavaScript to Trigger Div on Page w/ Certain Body Class On Button Click

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a page with:

```
<body class="Test">
```

And I have a button on the page as follows:

```
<div id="FinishButton">
```

And then I have a div on the page as below:

```
<div class="slide-1">
```

And then I have a hidden div as follows:

```
<div class="slide-2">
```

**How can I use JavaScript to make slide-2 appear and slide-1 disappear when I click that button ONLY on a page with the body class of "Test"?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('.Test'>'#FinishButton').click(function(){
        $('.slide-1').hide();
        $('.slide-2').show();
    })
```